# Identify the space group isomorphism between the the group created by AffineCrystGroup and the one given by cryst package

Tags: gap-system

I use the following code snippet to create the diamond space group in GAP with the help of [cryst package](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/cryst/htm/CHAP002.htm):

```
gap> M1:=[[0, 0, 1, 0],[1, 0, 0, 0],[0, -1, 0, 0],[1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1]];;
gap> M2:=[[0,0,-1,0],[0,-1,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1]];;
gap> S:=AffineCrystGroup([M1,M2]);
<matrix group with 2 generators>
```

The above code snippet comes from page 21 of the book [`Computer Algebra and Materials Physics`](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-94226-1), as shown below:

```
# As for the diamond case, in the GAP computation, the 
# crystallographic group is defined as follows. (The minimal
# generating set is used for simplicity.)
gap> M1:=[[0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,-1,0,0],[1/4,1/4,1/4,1]];;
gap> M2:=[[0,0,-1,0],[0,-1,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1]];;
gap> S:=AffineCrystGroup([M1,M2]);
<matrix group with 2 generators>
gap> P:=PointGroup(S);
Group([ [ [ 0, 0, 1 ], [ 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, -1, 0 ] ],
[ [ 0, 0, -1 ], [ 0, -1, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0 ] ] ])
```

It's well-known that diamond has the space group [`Fd-3m (No. 227)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond#Crystal_structure). I wonder how I can verify/confirm/check this fact in GAP after I've created the above `AffineCrystGroup`.

Regards,
HZ

Comment: This question might be better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crystallography

Comment: Ah, I see! I didn't know that rule. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20982/problem-you-have-reached-your-question-limit and https://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans for some tips. In particular, you could try to edit one of your downvoted or closed questions. Closed questions will be placed in the review queue for reopening after you edit them.

Comment: Also, where `M1` and `M2` are coming from?

Comment: 1. Thank you for the tips. 2. I have added descriptions of their source material.

Comment: 1) Screenshots instead of text are usually frowned upon. They are not searchable and not editable. 2) https://math.stackexchange.com/ has LaTeX support while this site is not. 3) This is really a question that belongs to https://math.stackexchange.com/  and not here. You have two sources with different generating sets for apparently the same group, and you would like to check that they are equivalent. I suggest to try to improve your profile to be able to post it at https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: By saying `improve your profile`, do you mean `edit one of your downvoted or closed questions`, as you suggested above?

Comment: Yes - you need to overcome the question limit, and that seems to be the way to do this.

Comment: @OlexandrKonovalov I've reposted the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4450721/identify-the-space-group-international-table-number-from-the-group-created-by-af).

Comment: No, please don't vandalise old questions this way. That was a proper question, useful, although closed. I've reverted your attempt. You need to ask a new one. "Edit" in "edit one of your downvoted or closed questions" means "edit to improve it", not "edit to replace by a completely different question".

Comment: It seems that it is not easy for me to do what you describe at present. All the questions I have asked are actually not easy to polish from this perspective, at least in my current opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the command **ConjugatorSpaceGroups** provided by the cryst package, as described [here](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/cryst/htm/CHAP002.htm#SSEC008.6), I figured out the following solution:

```
gap> M1OnRight:=[[0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,-1,0,0],[1/4,1/4,1/4,1]];;
gap> M2OnRight:=[[0,0,-1,0],[0,-1,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1]];;
gap> SG227OnRight:=AffineCrystGroupOnRight([M1OnRight,M2OnRight]);
<matrix group with 2 generators>
gap> ConjugatorSpaceGroups(SG227OnRight, SpaceGroupOnRightIT(3,227));
[ [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 3/8, 3/8, 7/8, 1 ] ]
```

Comment: This answer, just containing GAP commands, is quite cryptic. Would be nice to explain the strategy you are trying to apply here.